# UISearchResultController under my UISearchBar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

The problem is as it is on the image below:

[image]

My **searchResultController** is a subclass of `UITableViewController` and is under my `UISearchBar`:

This is how I custom this:

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    searchResultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(DBSearchResultControllerIdentifier) as! DBSearchResultController
    searchResultController.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self

    searchBarContainerView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}
```

How to fix that problem?